# How process SOAP Message with attachment in CXF

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, soap

I am new in this technologic and i would like some ideas of how I get a binaryFile with attachment in JAVA.

The Response that I recived was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns4:downloadSignResponse xmlns:ns2="urn:juntadeandalucia:cice:pfirma:query:v2.0" xmlns:ns3="urn:juntadeandalucia:cice:pfirma:type:v2.0" xmlns:ns4="urn:juntadeandalucia:cice:pfirma:query:request:v2.0"><signature><sign>true</sign><signFormat>PDF</signFormat><content><xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:5f190bbe-54a2-4b63-8053-2d14908ca492-4601@cxf.apache.org"/></content></signature></ns4:downloadSignResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

BUT I need get the file with ID  -> cid:5f190bbe-54a2-4b63-8053-2d14908ca492-5042@cxf.apache.org.

I am use JAVA with maven and spring-mvc

Thanks.